# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Magento breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 24         17
Users destroyed                                  26          0
Users deleted                                    38          0
Users contacted                                  52          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           137     21,964
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                5        957
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         24     12,048
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                1      3,351
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                10      6,977
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               71     10,066
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          2
Tag synonyms created                              0          1
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions reopened                               30         20
Questions protected                               1         61
Questions migrated                               12          6
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1      2,039
Questions closed                                196      1,627
Question flags handled⁴                         318      1,722
Posts unlocked                                    0          4
Posts undeleted                                  37        430
Posts locked                                      1         66
Posts deleted⁵                                1,640      9,649
Posts bumped                                      0      8,720
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  0      3,503
Comments deleted⁶                               673      6,392
Comment flags handled                           882      2,621
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                   0      6,149
Answer flags handled                          3,433      2,716
All comments on a post moved to chat             10          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...